# How to intersect lists or specify AND condition using Overpass QL

Tags: intersection, overpass-api

I am trying to find residential buildings that are within 1km of a subway station, a gym, and a supermarket. No matter what I do, I get a union of those lists instead of an intersection.

```
[out:json][timeout:250];
(
  node["railway"="station"]["station"="subway"]({{bbox}})->.metros;
  node["leisure"="fitness_centre"]({{bbox}})->.gyms;
  node["shop"="supermarket"]({{bbox}})->.supermarkets;
  
  way(around.metros:1000)["building"~"residential|house|apartments|detached|terrace|semidetached_house"]->.residential_near_metros;
  way(around.gyms:1000)["building"~"residential|house|apartments|detached|terrace|semidetached_house"]->.residential_near_gyms;
  way(around.supermarkets:1000)["building"~"residential|house|apartments|detached|terrace|semidetached_house"]->.residential_near_supermarkets;
  node(w.residential_near_metros)(w.residential_near_gyms)(w.residential_near_supermarkets);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

What should I do to get the intersection? I have been suggested to run 3 queries and intersect the results server-side but I'd really much rather make this query work if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters could be chained: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1B3S

```
[out:json][timeout:250];

node["railway"="station"]["station"="subway"]({{bbox}})->.metros;
node["leisure"="fitness_centre"]({{bbox}})->.gyms;
node["shop"="supermarket"]({{bbox}})->.supermarkets;
  
way(around.metros:1000)(around.gyms:1000)(around.supermarkets:1000)["building"~"residential|house|apartments|detached|terrace|semidetached_house"];
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```